# Move "handmade" htaccess to nginx config

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

The main problem is code which has converted by https://winginx.com/htaccess is not working. When trying open page it has just white paper without any debug messages.

Already have nginx config:

```
server {

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                rewrite ^/course-track/* https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
                rewrite ^/course-category/* https://websitw.com/profile/? redirect;
    }
        location /extra-online-testing/ {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ https://website.com/tests/extra-online-testing/ redirect;
        }

        location = /my-courses/ {
               rewrite ^(.*)$ https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
        }
        location = /courses/ {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
        }
}
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-courses/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://website.com/profile/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/course-track/*
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://website.com/profile/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/courses/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://website.com/profile/? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/course-category/*
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://website.com/profile/? [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /extra-online-testing/ https://website.com/tests/extra-online-testing/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried another converters, but had same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :), let me know if this works for you :)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name your_domain.com;

        location / {
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }




          location = /my-courses/ {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
      }

          location / {
          rewrite ^/course-track/* https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
          rewrite ^/course-category/* https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
      }

          location = /courses/ {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
      }

          location /extra-online-testing/ {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ https://website.com/tests/extra-online-testing/ redirect;
      }

          location / {
          rewrite ^/course-category/* https://website.com/profile/? redirect;
      }


}
```

Comment: Nope. It is not work. Firstly because it has three "location /". I've tried move all code from localtion / to end of the document, but it's was not help.